# Jackson json deserialization with integer(primitive data) as the key into POJO

Tags: java, rest, jackson, json-deserialization

In one of the APIs, I'm receiving this as the Json response:
You can check this response sample here [Sample Json resopnse](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bUwhxXvibm?indent=4)

```
{
    "histogram" : {
        "1" : "12",
        "2" : "20",
        "3" : "50",
        "4" : "90",
        "5" : "10"
     }
}
```

**In order to deserialize this response, How does one even write the POJO classes ?**

In java, since we are not allowed to have numbers as the variable names, how does one convert this into a POJO?

For instance, how can I create something like this:

```
public class MyPOJO {
    Histogram histogram;

    public static class Histogram {
        // I KNOW THIS IS WRONG !!
        String 1;
        String 2;
        String 3;
        String 4;
    }
}
```

Does jackson provide any annotations to handle these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this JSON:

```json
{
  "histogram": {
    "1": "12",
    "2": "20",
    "3": "50",
    "4": "90",
    "5": "10"
  }
}
```

You can consider one of the the following approaches:

### Using a `Map<String, String>` to hold the values

The `histogram` can the parsed into a `Map<String, String>`:

```java
public class HistogramWrapper {

    @JsonProperty("histogram")
    private Map<String, String> histogram;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

### Using attributes annotated with `@JsonProperty`

Alternatively, you can define a `Histogram` class and annotate its attributes with [`@JsonProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html):

```java
public class HistogramWrapper {

    @JsonProperty("histogram")
    private Histogram histogram;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Histogram {

    @JsonProperty("1")
    private String _1;

    @JsonProperty("2")
    private String _2;

    @JsonProperty("3")
    private String _3;

    @JsonProperty("4")
    private String _4;

    @JsonProperty("5")
    private String _5;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

### Parsing the JSON

To parse the JSON, do as following:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{\"histogram\":{\"1\":\"12\",\"2\":\"20\","
            + "\"3\":\"50\",\"4\":\"90\",\"5\":\"10\"}}";

HistogramWrapper wrapper = mapper.readValue(json, HistogramWrapper.class);
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I had forgotten about representing histogram as a HashMap. Histogram can be represented as a key value pair. Thanks :)

Comment: @oathkeeper Please have a look at my update. You also can use `@JsonProperty`.

Comment: I did. I'm not concerned with the exact accuracy of the answer. The concept is far more important. I remembered the concept. Thansk :)

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to Cassio's answer, In case you have a Json response such as this

```
{
        "1": 12, 
        "3": 50, 
        "2": 20, 
        "5": 10, 
        "4": 90, 
        "7": 20, 
        "6": 322
}
```

You can directly serialize and deserialize them back and forth into a HashMap. No POJOs needed.

```
    String jsonString = "{\"1\":\"12\",\"2\":\"20\","
                + "\"3\":\"50\",\"4\":\"90\",\"5\":\"10\"}";

    HashMap<String, Integer> histogramMap;

    histogramMap = (new ObjectMapper()).
    readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<HashMap<Integer, String>>(){});
```

This will directly save it as a HashMap.